# Refresh JSON Data Using Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Just finished a Codeacademy tutorial using angular to loop through some JSON data from a URL and display the data.

Would love to know how to implement it so the data would be updated if the JSON data was changing periodically!

I know I need to maybe refresh the http get request,but after that I'm not sure.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

services/forecast.js

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 
return $http.get('http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json') 
        .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
}]);
```

controllers/MinorController.js

```
app.controller('MinorController', ['$scope', 'forecast', function($scope, forecast) { 

 var setTimeOut = setInterval(function () {
          forecast.success(function(data) { 
          $scope.fiveDay = data; 
        });
       }, 5000);

       $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (scope, next, current) {
           if (next.$$route.controller != "MinorController") {
               clearInterval(setTimeOut); // clear interval here
           }
       });    
}]);
```

test.html  (view)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Angular -->
<script src="js/shared/angular.min.js"></script>


<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="js/shared/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

        <div class="container" ng-controller="MinorController">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Time JSON Example</h1>
            <h2>{{ fiveDay.tz }} </h2>
            <h2> {{ fiveDay.hour }} </h2>
            <h2> {{ fiveDay.datetime }} </h2>
            <h2> {{fiveDay.second }} </h2>
            </div>



        </div>

<!-- Modules -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/MinorController.js"></script>

<!-- Services -->
<script src="js/services/forecast.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can do ti by using interval

Comment: The problem I have is the data in the JSON object isn't actually changing so I can't really test it properly. The code you provided below still shows the data all the same!

Comment: hmm, I think your back-end data may by does not changed on run time, So you still seeing the same(old) data. Once your back-end(database)  data is changed, then you can see the changed data on run time .

Comment: Thanks a mil. I'm going to try it out on some data that is changing and let you know!

Comment: Ok so changed the back-end data to use this data http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json, and added the code you provided. The data is being displayed, but isn't updating as the data updates!

Comment: put break point for the service success function, please check your data change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75106/discussion-between-user2085143-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Comment: Still need help on this!

Comment: This question doesn't fit into the format for SO. This is too broad, please come back with a specific question not a "how can I implement this thought" question.

Comment: In what way does it not fit the format?

Comment: Your question is "Would love to know how to implement it so the data would be updated if the JSON data was changing periodically" whereas questions normally fit into something like "Here's what I'm trying to do and what I've tried" yours is (paraphrased) more like "I want to complete this action please point my in the right direction"

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `setInterval` like so.

```
app.controller('MinorController', ['$scope', 'forecast', function($scope, forecast) {
    var setTimeOut = setInterval(function () {
        forecast.success(function(data) {
            $scope.fiveDay = data;
        });
    }, 5000);

    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (scope, next, current) {
        if (next.$$route.controller != "MinorController") {
            clearInterval(setTimeOut); // clear interval here
        }
    });
}]);
```

- Now your service will call every 5 seconds and rebind your object.
- If you go to another screen, then the `routeChangeStart` event will call for the interval to be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on several ways:

- You can make http request in loop every few seconds

  `setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);`
- If you develop server data source you can setup real time connection, using i.e. `SignalR` or `Socket`